# ActionScript Frame metadata not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I know there exist a lot of posts about the Frame metadata tag in ActionScript,
but I still didn't find an answer to my question.

The problem is, I have specified a Frame metadata tag above my Main class header:

```
package gameUI {
...
    [Frame(factoryClass="gameUI.MyPreloader")]
    public class Main extends Sprite { 

        public function Main()
        {
            if (stage)
                init();
            else
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void
        { ...
```

I also have a preloader class in the same package (gameUI) called MyPreloader.as

```
package gameUI
{
    // imports..

    public class MyPreloader extends MovieClip 
    {
        // private vars ..

        public function MyPreloader() 
        {
            trace('preloader START');
            ...
```

In my  IDE, i don't get any errors or warnings. It compiles without problems.
But when I run it, it just skips over the Frame meta tag and just runs the code of the Main class. (The trace in the constructor of MyPreloader is never printed out).

I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with some arguments specified in the compiler settings. I've tried some couple of things, aditional compiler arguments but it never worked.

Does anyone know why he ignores the Frame metatag?
I'm really frustrated right now..

I'm using Flash Builder 4.6.
Compiling with Flex SDK 4.6.

thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Your Main Class is a Sprite, so it can't have two frames. That may be part of your problem.

However, it might be that you can use a process that's easier to debug to accomplish the ultimate goal. For example, this is [one approach](http://www.8bitrocket.com/2008/04/22/tutorial-preloading-actionscript-3-as3-games-in-flash-cs3/). I personally usually just set my default export frame as 10, put a spinner on frame 1 and issue a play().

The only assets that need to be compiled on Frame 1 are in the spinner. It will then pause while the spinner spins and the assets load (because it has to load everything compiled there before it can proceed). Once all the assets have loaded, it will naturally advance to Frame 10. I will have an instance on the timeline at Frame 10 that has an associated getter and setter, so when the setter triggers, I know that loading is complete.

I only check "Export in Frame 10" for assets that absolutely have to be loaded at startup (for example, sounds or visual objects that are never used on the timeline).

The advantage of this approach is that you can get to the real content earlier (because only assets compiled on your default frame have to load before you can show anything), but the disadvantage is that it makes no sense to show % progress, since you have no idea what percent of the movie is compiled on frame 10 and needs to load before it will start.

So, in summary:

1. Try making the Base Class for your fla a MovieClip
2. If that doesn't work, consider changing approach

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed my parent class of Main to a MovieClip, but still, it doesn't change a thing. I will be trying your other approach in the next couple of days. I'll keep you informed!